# vuforia with unity: application playing but unable to render real world

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I follow this guide ([How-to-build-an-ar-android-app-with-vuforia-and-unity](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-an-ar-android-app-with-vuforia-and-unity/)) but added my own mobile picture in database (as a marker) so that I could see animated object on my mobile and i am able to run my app but camera is not rendering the real world object in scene. instead animated object showing only.
what i am doing wrong?
[image]

Remember vuforia doesn't recognize my web-cam profile and apply default profile on it.(can be this )

Comment: what type of object did you add in database?

Comment: i added 2D image of my mobile, i have also added a simple texture but it is not working